# Combine Strings in Spark/Scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I have case where i have to combine a String with a RDD out(String)

String 1

```
date=
```

String 2 (RDD of String)

```
20140101
20140102
20140103
....
```

Output as

```
date=20140101, date=20140102, date=20140103,.....
```

Please help me to achieve this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark you would do that like this:

```
// Some sample data in an RDD
val data = List("20140101", "20140102", "20140103")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

val concatenated = rdd.map(elem => s"date=$elem").reduce(_ + ", " + _)
```

Be aware that`reduce` is an action. Therefore the result of reduce needs to fit in the memory of the driver.

Comment: To avoid the trailing comma: `val concatenated = rdd.map(elem => s"date=$elem").reduce(_ + ", " + _)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string2.map(d => s"$string1=$d").mkString(",")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i need it as a combined string. All tuple should be concatenated. this solution doesn't give the concatenated value. Ideally i should do flatmap to translate rows into columns(just for example)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, I get a RDD[String] of distinct dates and i have a String variable val foo = "date=". I need to concatenate both the outputs and output should be a string i.e. date=20140901,date=20140921,date=20140929... comma separated.

Comment: Right, how about this?

val foo = "date"
val strings = sc.parallelize(Seq("20140901", "20140921", "20140929"))
strings.map(str => s"$foo=$str").reduce(_ + ", " + _)

If you have an iterable of type String (instead of an RDD), you could apply the mkString method that I mentioned